# Approximate pi using series

Tags: python, series, pi

[image: instructions on how to get the pi]

```py
def approximate_pi():
    EPSILON = 1.0e-7
    term = 1
    n = 0
    sum_pi = 0
    while term > EPSILON:
        term = 4 * (((-1) ** (n)) / (2 * n + 1))
        sum_pi += term
        n += 1
    print(float(round(sum_pi,10)))
```

This is the code I have so far. What am I doing wrong here?
It needs to print out 3.1415924536

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Please check your indentation, the code given won't run with the current formatting. Also, please describe the problem or how your current output is different than expected

Comment: Take a closer look at the formula given in your assignment. Your approach does not match the formula.

Comment: One problem is that the test `term > EPSILON` is False the first time n is uneven, making term a negative number. You also seem to include the last term, while it is asked not to include it.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. See [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  We also expect you to supply the actual output, and usually a trace of the internal operation.  One or two simple `print` commands will show several of your problems.

Answer (score 0):

The assignment specifically mentions that the next term has to be less than epsilon in **absolute value**. This means you have to use `abs(term)` to get a positive number. Every negative number will be less than epsilon. Your while should check `abs(term) > EPSILON`.

Answer (score 0):

Some remarks:

- The test `term < EPSILON` is always `True` when `n` is uneven, so everything stops much too early.
- The assignment asks not to include the last term, so a test is needed before adding the term to the sum.
- You included the `4 *` in the term, while in reality it is outside the summation. You need to take this into account, either by also multiplying EPSILON by 4, or by multiplying at the very end. Multiplying only once at the end is faster than multiplying each individual term.
- Calculating `(-1) ** n` can be quite slow if you only want a sign that changes between odd and even n. It is faster to have an explicit variable that constantly switches between `-1` and `+1`. This also helps to always have the term as a positive number, removing the need for absolute value in the EPSILON test.

```py
def approximate_pi():
    EPSILON = 1.0e-7
    n = 0
    sum_pi = 0
    sign = 1
    while True:
        term = 1 / (2 * n + 1)
        if term < EPSILON:
            break
        sum_pi += sign * term
        n += 1
        sign = -sign
    return float(round(4 * sum_pi, 10))

print(approximate_pi())
```

This prints exactly `3.1415924536`

Comment: Was this answer helpful?